# solvePnPRansac returns different results

Tags: opencv, ransac

I use `solvePnPRansac` function in an Android application.
With identical input parameters it returns different results (rvec, tvec and status).

Is this normal behaviour or do i have memory corruptions?

Answer (score 5):

This is normal for RANSAC:  **RANdom** SAmple Consensus

The random is the part that is responsible for slightly different results in every run.